# prove an inequality for diagonals of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

in a quadrilateral $ABCD$, all angles except $A$ are greater than $90^\circ$. How would I prove $AC>BD$?
I tried to use the triangle inequality and ptolemy's inequality, but I can't find anything

Comment: You will have better luck getting an answer if you show us some of the work you have done already, such as elaborating on how you tried to apply the "triangle inequality and ptolmy's inequality". It may also help you to draw a diagram of your problem

Comment: @lioness99a I just wrote down ptolemy's inequality as it is $AB \cdot CD + AD \cdot BC \geq AC \cdot BD$. I already drew a diagram but its just a quad with diagonals.

Comment: I'm not certain of how to solve the problem, but a diagram with the quadrilateral and the circle passing through $B, C, D$ looked promising.

Comment: @MatthewDaly so $BD \leq 2R$...thats all I have

Comment: Yeah, and $A$ is outside the circle.  That doesn't immediately show that $AC>2r$, but you'd be done if you could show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let be $c$ the circle through the points $B,C,D$.
2. Le be $r$ the half-line orthogonal to $BC$ in $B$.
3. Le be $s$ the half-line orthogonal to $DC$ in $D$.
4. Let be $J$ the common point of $r$ and $s$. We have that $J\in c$.
5. In order to have the angle of vertex $A$ less than a right angle, and the other angles greater than $90°$, $A$ must be a point inside the angle $\angle MJN $.
6. Let be $t$  the half-line with origin in $C$ through $J$.
7. From $A$ we trace the segment perpendicular to $t$ with end-points on $r$ and $s$.
8. Le be $K$ the intersection point of $t$ and $EL$.
9. Now we have that $AC>CK$ since it is the hypotenuse of the triangle $ACK$.
10. It is $CK>JC=2R$ where $R$ is the radius of $c$ so $AC>2R$.
11. Since $BD\leq 2R$ we have done.
    [image]

Comment: oh forgot to edit that I found the solution,
you add a circle in which AC is the diameter. Then the obtuse angles must be inside the circle, and a line inside the circle is shorter than the diameter... but I guess yours works too.